# How do I map a column of string values in one dataframe to another column in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

Dataframe A contains the following column and values -

| Column 1 |
| --- |
| A; B; C |
| A; D; E |
| B; C |

Dataframe B contains the following columns and values -

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | Apple |
| B | Banana |
| C | Cat |
| D | Dog |
| E | Egg |

Now, I want to map the values in Column 1 of Dataframe 2 to the values in Column 1 of Dataframe 1 to obtain the following column in Dataframe 1:

| Column 1 | Derived Column |
| --- | --- |
| A; B; C | Apple; Banana; Cat |
| A; D; E | Apple; Dog; Egg |
| B; C | Banana; Cat |

My first thought was to iterate through each row in Dataframe 1, split the value in column 1 by ';', and then map it to Dataframe 2, but I have ~100k rows in Dataframe 1, and ~10k rows in Dataframe 2 which would make this computationally expensive. Is there a much faster way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `series.replace` with `regex=True` after creating a dict from the second df:

```
df1['Column 2'] = df1['Column 1'].replace(df2.set_index('Column 1')
                                           ['Column 2'],regex=True)
```

---

```
print(df1)

  Column 1            Column 2
0  A; B; C  Apple; Banana; Cat
1  A; D; E     Apple; Dog; Egg
2     B; C         Banana; Cat
```

Comment: Nice one man. +1. I was thinking to split and explode and then map. This looks way better.

Comment: Thanks, man! This is pretty elegant. Worked for me.